# module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'EmbeddedField'

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-venv, djongo

New to python, and getting the above error writing a simple model.  I am developing on VSCode if that matters.  Below are my packages, installed in venv.

```
    asgiref==3.5.0
    Django==4.0.3
    djongo==1.3.6
    dnspython==2.2.1
    Pillow==9.0.1
    pymongo==4.0.2
    pytz==2022.1
    sqlparse==0.2.4
```

Just a simple model to test...

```
    from django.db import models

    class ItemSku(models.Model):
       ProductSku = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class ItemsCollection(models.Model):
       ProductName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
       ProductDescription = models.CharField(max_length=300)
       ProductFeatures = models.CharField(max_length=300) 
       ProductCategory = models.CharField(max_length=300)
       ProductCountryOfOrigin = models.CharField(max_length=30)
       ProductSkus =  models.EmbeddedField(ItemSku)
```

One other thing, is that I can connect to mongodb using djongo, and am able to makemigrations and migrate and view in Django admin without the 'EmbeddedField', I am just not able to create an embedded document.

I hope this makes sense.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really experienced with Django but to use EmbeddedField (and use MongoDB as your database using djongo) you need to import djongo, so you need to replace

```py
from django.db import models
```

by

```py
from djongo import models
```

[you should also check this from djongo's doc](https://www.djongomapper.com/get-started/#embeddedfield)